# AWS API Gateway only passing 1st variable to function, but lambda test passes all

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm finding this odd issue where AWS is passing the URL String parameters to a Lambda function properly but there is a break down in API gateway only when Lambda runs a Python handler function that calls

```
KeywordSearch(keyword,page,RPP)
```

that passes 3 variables to keywordSearch. In the lambda IDE test, it works without issue and prints out all 3 variables as seen in the logs as

```
InsideKeywordSearch, Vars=: 
keyword: 
bombing
 page: 
1
 RPP: 
10
```

But when I run an API Gateway test the log is showing the variable is not passed into the function as seen in the log showing no variable for RPP or Page.

The keyword is passed only. Am I not defining the function correctly? it works in Lambda why not API gateway if this is so?
here is a snippet of the code.

Function Call

```
def handler(event, context):
print('Inside Handler Funciton')
keyword = event.get('search_keyword', None)
id = event.get('id', None)
RPP = event.get('RPP', 10)
page = event.get('page', 1)
#get event variables, if passed and filter bad input
print("keyword")
print(keyword)
print("id")
print(id)
print('RPP')
print(RPP)
print('page')
print(page)
if keyword is not None:
    return keywordSearch(keyword,page,RPP)
elif id is not None:
    return idSearch(id)
else:
    return ""
```

Function

```
def keywordSearch (keyword, page, RPP):
    print('InsideKeywordSearch, Vars=: ')
    print("keyword: ")
    print(keyword)
    print(" page: ")
    print(page)
    print(" RPP: ")
    print(RPP)
```

Lambda Logs shows

Function Logs:

```
6d Version: $LATEST
Inside Handler Funciton
keyword
bombing
id
None
RPP
10
page
1
InsideKeywordSearch, Vars=: 
keyword: 
bombing
 page: 
1
 RPP: 
10
[INFO]  2018-06-30T03:04:56.240Z    5dc7a2cc-7c12-11e8-8f39-f5112d2e976d    SUCCESS: Connection to RDS mysql instance succeeded
```

API Gateway call shows

```
{
  "errorMessage": "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/app.py",
      144,
      "handler",
      "return keywordSearch(keyword,page,RPP)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/app.py",
      93,
      "keywordSearch",
      "sql = f\"SELECT attackid, SUM(MATCH(attack_fulltext) AGAINST('%{keyword}%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) as score FROM search_index WHERE MATCH(attack_fulltext) AGAINST('%{keyword}%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) GROUP BY attackid ORDER BY score DESC Limit { ((page-1)*RPP) },{(RPP)};\""
    ]
  ]
}
```

Which tells me that it's not passing the variables because the SQL sting becomes invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the API gateway was passing in a number as a string. I had to fix the get method mapping template in integration request as follows

In order to pass variables from API Gateway to back-end as integers, the quotes around the variable values need to be removed. Please make sure the values are getting passed as an integer from the client otherwise you will get the same error that you mentioned in your initial correspondence. In this case, I update the body mapping template from:

```
{
    "search_keyword" : "$input.params('search_keyword')",
    "page": "$input.params('page')",
    "RPP": "$input.params('RPP')"
}
```

to:

```
{
    "search_keyword" : "$input.params('search_keyword')",
    "page": $input.params('page'),
    "RPP": $input.params('RPP')
}
```